# How to prove connectivity $\leq$ minimum degree?

Tags: graph-theory

For a simple graph (no loops or multiple edges), how to prove that the connectivity is equal to or smaller than the minimum degree?

I just have no idea. I hope the answer could give me a general idea of how proofs in graph theory look like. Thank you.

To clarify, some of the definitions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the minimum degree of a graph $G$. Then, there is some vertex $v$ with $d$ neighbours. Provided that there are at least $d + 2$ vertices in $G$, the removal of the $d$ neighbours of $v$ will disconnect $v$ from the remainder of the graph, and will therefore cause $G$ to be disconnected. Thus, as there exists a cut set of $G$ of size $d$, $\kappa(G) \le d$.

If there are not at least $d + 2$ vertices in $G$, then there must be exactly $d + 1$ vertices, as otherwise, the minimum degree of $G$ cannot be $d$. Therefore, as $1 \le \kappa(G) \le |G| - 2$, and $|G| = d + 1$, $\kappa(G) \le d - 1 < d$, so $\kappa(G) \le d$.

Answer (score 2):

(Vertex connectivity assumed, as in updated question.) Let $d$ be the minimum degree. There is some $v$ with $d$ edges. Remove those $d$ other nodes incident to those edges. The graph is now disconnected unless we removed all other nodes (in which case the graph was complete etc.) Therefore the minimum number of nodes you must remove is at most $d$.

---

(Edge connectivity assumed.) Let $d$ be the minimum degree. There is some $v$ with $d$ edges. Remove those $d$ edges. The graph is now disconnected. Therefore the minimum number of edges you must remove is at most $d$.

Comment: Thanks. Seem we have different definition of connectivity, but yours seems better for this question.

Comment: There are two different inequivalent definitions; either work for this result. I've included the one relevant to your definition, namely vertex connectivity.

Comment: "The graph is now disconnected unless we removed all other nodes (in which case the graph was complete etc.)" To be more specific, here only one vertex is left, so by the [definition](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Consider-a-graph-of-only-1-vertex-and-no-edges-Is-it-connected-or-disconnected/56a9ce9e5cd9e302bb8b456b/citation/download) of vertex connectivity, it has vertex connectivity $n-1$.